# Image uploading to Cloudinary Failed in Android

Tags: java, android, cloudinary, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image to Cloudinary after clicking the image from the camera.
The camera is working fine but after clicking the image, the application is crashing again and again. Tried to debug it but not getting where I am having the error.

```
LOGCAT:
beginning of crash
05-03 00:29:58.243 4880-4880/com.example.maaz.taxit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.maaz.taxit, PID: 4880
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.maaz.taxit/com.example.maaz.taxit.ImageDeleteTest}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.cloudinary.android.MultipartUtility.<init>(MultipartUtility.java:52)
        at com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy.callApi(UploaderStrategy.java:48)
        at com.cloudinary.Uploader.callApi(Uploader.java:22)
        at com.cloudinary.Uploader.upload(Uploader.java:55)
        at com.example.maaz.taxit.ImageDeleteTest.onActivityResult(ImageDeleteTest.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I tried to hard code the sample image URL's but still it is not working.
May be the issue is with this line
`cloudinary.uploader().upload(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), ObjectUtils.emptyMap());`

```java
public static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //File to upload to cloudinary
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pakistan Zinabad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Map config = new HashMap();
                config.put("cloud_name", "nomancloud");
                config.put("api_key", "myKey");
                config.put("api_secret", "mySecretApi");
                Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);

                try {
                    cloudinary.uploader().upload(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
                //finish();
            }
        }

    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

        String imageFileName = "capturedImage";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        return image;
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePhotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        photoFile = null;

        try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using:

```
Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg", ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
```

And print the RuntimeException/uploadResult?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MediaManager class for android provided by Cloudinary. You will need to call the dispatch() method which will run on a background thread. Basically you are getting NetworkOnMainThread exception which means you are doing network calls on the UI thread with Android does not allow. Check the documentation, its easy.

```
    String requestId = MediaManager.get().upload("imageFile.jpg")
   .unsigned("sample_preset")
   .dispatch();
```

A snippet from docs.

Checkout this link to learn more:

[Cloudinary upload documentation page](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_image_and_video_upload)